# Situation of detached std::thread after parrent thread left its block

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I've searched but i couldnt find exact answer of this question.
For instance, if we have a code block like this:

```
{
  std::thread thread_1(.....);
  thread_1.detach();
  ...
}
```

when thread_1  still works, what happens exactly after parent thread left this code block.

Comment: IMHO, in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) everything is clear. The example is exactly the case.

Comment: @megabyte1024 yes I saw that example but I couldnt be sure because there is similar ambiguity about what happens other threads after main() complated its own block. can we be sure whether it will work any os and compiler like in that example or not?

Comment: No one can be sure that any OS and/or any compiler works as prescribes the standard. But it is a problem of the implementation and not a problem of the standard.

Comment: What happens? Execution continues. The thread is detached, so any interaction that your program has with it has to come through shared variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** I am running this on a very bad **operating system,** or maybe very primitive, then as you have **detached** the `thread` from `main` thread, so it works in a **independently** of the `main` thread. So even though the main thread exits, it will keep on running as long as it is not dependent on any variables present at **global** scope, it will be stray thread.

**Case 2:** This is running on a **modern** opertaing system, we can say that it will behave as same as that in **case 1**, but modern OS on seeing a **widowed** thread will immediately **kill** **it** and clean it, releasing the **resources** *captured* by it.

**hope this is helpful, if incorrect please suggest corrections in the comments below...thankyou**